# 'Error:BrokenCount>0'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: apt

I'm receiving this error after my PC crash while installing some programs :

> 'Error:BrokenCount>0'
>   An error occurred. 
>   Please run the Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.
>   This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies."

I tried :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

without receiving any error messages. Then I tried

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and I got this :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  liburi-perl ubuntu-mono
Suggested packages:
  libwww-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  liburi-perl ubuntu-mono
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 280 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/530 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4 423 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 37412:
 invalid package name (character `/' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._'))
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: i just solve it before few sec , i go to file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' and i found in line 37412 a wrong caracter  (i found this ubuntu/mono) so i switched to ubuntu-mono instead 

then i tried sudo apt-get -f install again found other error in  file '/var/lib/dpkg/available'  so i fixed  and finally i repeat sudo apt-get -f install and then he told me to continue installing , i press Y and everything is good now , any way thnx for u guys